# VeeValidate 4 How to validate password and confirm password fileds?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vee-validate

I am trying to understand how one can validate a password and a confirm password field using vee validate and zod library.

I managed to understand how to use `useField` and `useForm` in separate components, but now I don't understand how can I validate values from two components.

For example, I have to following form and I want to validate that `password` field is the same with `confirm-password`

```
<!-- form file -->
<template>
    <form>
        <PasswordInput name="password" />
        <PasswordInput name="confirm-password" />
    </form>
</template>
<script setup>
const { handleSubmit } = useForm()

const onSubmit = handleSubmit((values, { resetForm }) => {
  alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
  resetForm();
});
</script
```

```
<!-- PasswordInput file -->
<template>
    <input type="password" :name="name" />
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
});
const validationSchema = toFieldValidator(z.string().min(1))

const nameRef = toRef(props, 'name');
const { errorMessage, value } = useField(nameRef, validationSchema);
</script>
```

I don't quite understand how can I do this validation
I know `zod` has a method using the `refine` method, but I don't understand how can I use it in two different components

I tried to use validationSchema object in `useForm`, but then the form and its fields are valid by default

Do you have any tips for me?

Answer (score -1):

### 1. Define your rule

```js
import { defineRule } from 'vee-validate';

defineRule('confirmed', (value, [target]) => {
  if (value === target) {
    return true;
  }
  return 'Passwords must match';
});
```

### 2. In your component template use field like this

```js
<Form>
  <Field name="password" type="password" />
  <Field name="confirmation" type="password" rules="confirmed:@password" />
</Form>
```

`@` prefix in your rule tells `vee-validate` to automatically swap the specified field value in the arguments array and then in your rule `[target]` contains password field value.

This case describe in the [doc](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/global-validators/#cross-field-validation).